# How to trigger a github action job or workflow based on modified file or directory on last commit

Tags: github-actions

In Gitlabci, it's possible to trigger a specific job only if a file or a directory has been modified.

Is it possible to do the same thing with Github actions ?

Answer (score 9):

From the [documentation](https://help.github.com/en/github/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-including-paths):

```
on:
  push:
    paths:
    - '**.js'
```